# The app is always crashing when I am trying to import data from Firebase to list view

Tags: android-studio

```
    octDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Octave Spectrum");
    octList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.octaList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, octData);
```

//it works till this point and after this the app crashes the setAdapter function is not working for me
        octList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

```
    octDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String y = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            octData.add(y);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[This is the list i am trying to import from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyZ6P.png)

Comment: hello @Prajwal Khatiwada, can you say me what is octData? your list name is octList as you defined above right?

Comment: Please add the error log from logcat for better response.

Comment: octData is just a ArrayList @JanviVyas

Comment: my main target is to fetch the data from server, store it into array and then use the data from array to draw gram and do mathematical calculations like mean, median

Answer (score 0):

First, that is not clear what is octData? So as per I understood your listname is octList.

**Thus,you need to set list in third parameter of array adapter in your code** like below:-

```
octDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Octave Spectrum");
    octList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.octaList);
```

**Replace below line :-**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, octData);
```

**with :-**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, octList);
```